# TinyMCE Body.contentEditable=false don´t work in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, tinymce, contenteditable, readonly

I am using TinyMCE editor for my application and I want to have my body and the presentation toolbar on screen with "readonly", but

```
 readonly:true
```

makes the presentation bar disable which is not acceptable by client (needs both content area and toolbar).

I successully made the:

```
 body.contentEditable = false;
```

which works but only works in IE and chrome, not in firefox, I googled and I didn´t find any solution, also try:

```
removeAttr( 'contenteditable' );
```

or setting the

```
readonly:true;   
this.getBody().setAttribute('mceToolbar', true);
```

but any of them works.

Any way to solve the problem, or someone solved already this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved through a lot of investagations, well it works for me, I just made a diffent configuration for Firefox like:

```
getDoc().designMode  = "off";
```

Comment: I put another answer with the complet code, that solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(this.settings.setupcontent_callback_2=="customEditor"){
            //Explorer
            if(tinymce.isIE){
                this.getBody().contentEditable = false;
            }
            //FIREFOX & CHROME
            else if(tinymce.isGecko){
                this.getBody().contentEditable = false;
                this.getDoc().designMode  = "off";
            }
            else{//TODOS LOS DEMÁS (The others)
                this.getDoc().designMode  = "off";
                this.getBody().contentEditable = false;
            }
        }
```